# How to restart service after some time?

Tags: systemd

We have multiple systems that suffer from a firmware bug. The vendor is aware of the problem and will fix the firmware bug. Until then we have to live with a workaround: restart the relevant service some time after bootup.

There are mechanisms in systemd to control the restart of a failed service but they are not of help here because the service starts successfully. Just delaying the start of the service by - say - 1 minute does not help, it needs to be started twice.

So what's the best way to automatically restart a service after the system is up?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using cron in this case:

```
@reboot sleep 300 && systemctl restart yourservice
```

This should restart your service 5 minutes after the machine has booted

For more information see the Extension section in the crontab(5) manpage https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab

Comment: Nice, did not know this.

Answer (score 4):

Create [a .timer unit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52592734/4735500) to control the .service unit.

Use the same base name as the service, so if the service were called `thing`, in `/etc/systemd/system/foo.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Start broken thing twice

[Timer]
OnBootSec=1min
OnBootSec=2min

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Then enable this new timer. `systemctl enable thing.timer`

As the service remains active even if it has this problem, edit overrides such that it doesn't.  `systemctl edit thing.service`
Which to change is hard to say without seeing the original unit. Perhaps add a `ExecStartPost=`  command that returns 0 only if the device is in a good state.  Or change `RemainAfterExit=no` to force a oneshot to not stay active.